# Show profile information after login nodejs

Tags: node.js, routes

I am new in **Node.JS** API creation. I have successfully implemented login with **JWT** token and also I have created a file to verify and pass *token* in header.

This is my **login route :-**

```
router.post('/login' , (req, res, next) => {

    User.find({email: req.body.email})
    .exec()
    .then(user => {
        if(user.length < 1) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                message: "Auth failed. User not found."
            })
        }
        bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user[0].password, (err, result) =>{
            if (err) {
                return res.status(401).json({
                message: "Auth failed. Check email and password"
                });             
            }   
            if (result){
                const adminEmail = "tom@xyz.com";                                               
                const role = user[0].email===adminEmail? "admin" : "user";                                  
                const token = jwt.sign( 
                    {
                        email: user[0].email,
                        userId: user[0]._id,
                        role
                    },
                    process.env.JWT_KEY,
                    {
                        expiresIn : "1h"
                    });
                    return res.status(200).json({
                    message: "Auth Successful",
                    token : token
                    });
            }
        });
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        if (err.code == 500)
                    res.status(500).send(["Something went wrong in login"]);
            else
            return next(err);
    });
});
```

With this I am creating a JSON response in login:-

```
{
    "message": "Auth Successful",
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InRvbUB4eXouY29tIiwidXNlcklkIjoiNWMzMzI0MTgyNTg4M2I0Yzc0ODNkOGJjIiwicm9sZSI6InVzZXIiLCJpYXQiOjE1NDY5MzMwODYsImV4cCI60.zfRUQmg5K_mBU0Dkq72c0sgzFtCXvu8kObyvEflhg"
}
```

Now, I have also created a file to check authentication of user's. **check-auth.js**

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
module.exports = (req, rest, next) =>{ 
    try{
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
        console.log(token);
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY)
        req.userData = decoded;
        next();
    }
    catch(error){
        return res.status(401).json({
            message: "Auth failed"
        });
    }
};
```

I need user's to login and can only see the details which they have provided during the registration.

**registration route :-**

```
router.post('/register' , ctrlUser.register);
```

**user controller:-**

```
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');

module.exports.register = (req, res, next) =>{  
    var user = new User();
    user.fullName = req.body.fullName;
    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.password = req.body.password;
    user.phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber;
    user.save((err, doc) =>{
        if(!err)
            res.send(doc);
        else{
            if (err.code == 11000)
                    res.status(422).send(["Entered duplicate email address. Please check"]);
            else
            return next(err);
            }
    });
}
```

Here in **profile route** i need to show registration details after successful login :-

```
router.get('/profile', checkAuth, (req, res) =>{
    //something to do.
});
```

I am stuck here for a while.

Comment: Fetch the data from the database and show it? Not sure what you are stuck with.

Comment: @Sashi I don't want entire data to be fetched. I want data of a particular user who is logging in. Then there will be no use of authenticating a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to get the logged in user information.

Try the following code

```
router.get('/profile', checkAuth, (req, res) =>{
    //something to do.
    // printing the user data
    console.log(req.userData);

    // sending the user data
    res.send(req.userData)
});
```

In your `check-auth` middleware you already put the user data

```
req.userData = decoded;
```

So your `userData` should be available on the routes.

And since you used the user `mail` and `id` to get `jwt token` in sin in section,
they will be available in the `userData` object.

Comment: My login token and check-auth token is different when consoling it . Why so ?

Comment: Can you please explain the `login token` and `check-auth token`? Or show the console output result?

Comment: When I am logging in I get the following response. `{
    "message": "Auth Successful",
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InRvbUB4eXouY29tIiwidXNlcklkIjoiNWMzMzI0MTgyNTg4M2I0Yzc0ODNkOGJjIiwicm9sZSI6InVzZXIiLCJpYXQiOjE1NDY5MzgzMTMsImV4cCI6MTU0Njk0MTkxM30.GMdcp7UR5h0Nk-o6tvEX47sYkmMuKnR3-FUK2IoddwU"
}` . Now , when I am checking the `console.log` which I have mentioned in `check-auth.js` , there is no response.

Comment: In your `check-auth.js`,  can you check the `decoded` object value?

Comment: Ok now I can access my information thanks for your help.

Comment: Also , in this way we can access the data `router.get('/profile', checkAuth, (req, res, data) =>{
 User.find(req.userData, function(err, users) {
 res.send(req.userData);
  });
});`